# Spring Batch Failure Listener Rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, rollback

I am extending Spring Batch's `ItemListenerSupport` and overriding `onProcessError()` for dealing with error states. My problem is, I was expecting to be able to write to the database as part of my handling, but it seems its being included in the transaction for the batch and being rolled back. Is there a way to get it to do the rollback before and allow `onProcessError()` to update the db? Or is there some other way I should be handling this?

Comment: Can you actually verify that your changes are being made? It might be that your transaction is rolling back, and you don't have a valid database session available, with your exception being swallowed by your persistence provider.

Comment: Yes, we can see the update statement followed by 2 rollbacks, and finally 2 commits, which obviously won't do anything at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its right there in the documentation. Needed to add my own transaction.

> Remember that if your listener does anything in an onError() method, it will be inside a transaction that is going to be rolled back. If you need to use a transactional resource such as a database inside an onError() method, consider adding a declarative transaction to that method (see Spring Core Reference Guide for details), and giving its propagation attribute the value REQUIRES_NEW.